# change file permissions in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, kali-linux, effective-permissions

How to change file permissions to execute a binary executable ELF file in Kali Linux? I have been trying `chmod +x <filename>` and then running it with `./filename` but all I get is `Error: No file found`. Any other ideas? I even tried `chmod 777 <filename>`. I am wondering if there is anything I am missing?

Edit:

Output of `file <filename>:`

```
root@swat:~/Downloads# file talisman 
talisman: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, 
BuildID[sha1]=2b131df906087adf163f8cba1967b3d2766e639d, not stripped
```

Output of `ldd <filename>:`

```
root@swat:~/Downloads# ldd ./talisman 
not a dynamic executable
```

Output of `ls /lib:`

```
root@swat:~# ls /lib
console-setup  init                                  startpar
cpp            klibc-k3La8MUnuzHQ0_kG8hokcGAC0PA.so  systemd
crda           ld-linux.so.2                         terminfo
cryptsetup     live                                  udev
firmware       lsb                                   x86_64-linux-gnu
hdparm         modprobe.d
ifupdown       modules
```

Comment: That error message means that it's not a permissions issue, but perhaps a missing dependency, e.g. a shared library.  Edit your post, and add the output from shell commands `file <filename>`, `ldd <filename>`, and `ls /lib`.

Comment: This is likely a dup of https://superuser.com/a/375290/112397

Comment: @sawdust, edited the question with the output as requested. sorry took me time to get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves it.

```
root@swat:~/Downloads# readelf -l ./talisman | grep interpreter
[Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
```

Then I looked for the missing libraries by issuing this command:

```
root@swat:~/Downloads# ldd /bin/ls
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe9a971000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 
(0x00007fe90a8a7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe90a50a000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fe90a297000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe90a093000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056083d3b2000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 
(0x00007fe909e76000)
```

This confirms it that I do not have broken symbolic links for that library and that library `(/lib/ld-linux.so.2)` it is loading is not found in `/bin/ls`.

Issuing this fixes the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several cases where you can get the message “No such file or directory”:

- The file doesn't exist. This is not the case here.
- There is a file by that name, but it's a dangling symbolic link. The `chmod +x ./filename` would have printed an error if that was the case.
- The file is a dynamically linked ELF file, and the program interpreter that is required to run it does not exist.

  Use `readelf -l filename | grep interpreter` to find out which program interpreter is required, and verify that *it* exists and has correct permissions.
- The file exists, and you can even read it but when you try to execute it you are told that it doesn't exist.

The `file -L filename` command will tell you just what this binary is.

I can't find any example 32-bit Linux executable to try this with, but maybe you can just run the `file` command and verify whether the file is 32-bit or 64-bit. You might have a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system that doesn't have 32-bit support installed (this is special case of "program interpreter is missing").